# Verify duplicate files on upload on Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, file-upload

Am aploading a file and i wanna verify if the same file is already uploaded. The problem that am having is that it pass on my function right after clicking on upload it doesnt wait for me to choose the file to upload before passing by my function to verify the condition i made. i tried using ng-change and on change and none of em works.

Am using Angular JS to handle my front end. (Am a beginner)

```
function findFile(livrable) {
    
    return vm.livrables.find(function(livrablefichier) {// add an if here to check if the file is nulll
      if(livrablefichier == null) {
      return (
        livrablefichier.name         === livrable.name &&
        livrablefichier.lastModified === livrable.lastModified &&
        livrablefichier.size         === livrable.size &&
        livrablefichier.type         === livrable.type
      )
      }
    })
  }
  

  function verifyFiles(livrable){
    var livrableDejaExistant = false;
   livrable.dejaExistant  = false;
      if (findFile(livrable)) {
        livrableDejaExistant = true;
        livrable.dejaExistant = true;
         
      }
      else {
        livrableDejaExistant = false;
      }
```

i tried using ng-change and on change and none of em works.

```
        <div class="col-xs-4 soumission-livrable">
              <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="bouton-import-fichier debordementMasque">
                  <input type="file" id="{{livrable.fichier}}" name="{{livrable.fichier}}"
                         ng-disabled="!depotComposantCtrl.isAffichageBoutonMaj"
                         ng-change="depotComposantCtrl.verifyFiles(livrable)"
                         onchange="angular.element(this).scope().controleLivrableSansFichier()"
                         class="gererLongueurNomFichier">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```